# How can Swift protocol conform to type parameter protocol

Tags: swift, generics

I have following quite straight forward Swift 2.0 code

```
protocol PA {
    init(handle:Int)
}

class CB: PA {
    required init(handle:Int) {}
}

class X {
    func test<U:PA>() -> U {
        return U(handle: 1)
    }
}

class ThisFails {
    func foo() -> PA {
        return X().test()
    }
}
```

but it fails to compile with rather odd error message

> swift:23:20: error: generic parameter 'U' could not be inferred
>           return X().test()

I'd like U to be inferred as PA type

Changing return type of method `foo` to `CB` makes it work but I have many classes implementing PA protocol so that won't work for me.

Similarly removing PA constrain from U:PA and compiler infers it as PA type inside `foo` but I need to make constrained called inside `test` so that won't help me either.

Comment: it is 'normal'. test<U:PA>()->U is function with parameter of type U which return the instance of type U. foo return type is PA.Type, not type which conforms to PA, like U:PA. in other words, to make an instance from protocol.Type is impossible. try let a = Any(). it is not available  too.

Answer (score 0):

Well... the issue is stated quite clear in the error message!
Point is that you declared a function using generics, and the generic type has a constraint on a protocol. The method test() is then written using the generic U... which means that when you actually use the method it must be clear for the compiler what is the actual type conforming to the protocol PA to be instantiated and returned by test().
In the function foo this is not clear... how can you expect test to return CB when it is never mentioned? Try:

```
X().test<CB>()
```

Comment: wrong ... return X().test<CB>() should not works. you cannot explicitly specialize a generic function

Comment: You cannot explicitly specialize a generic function in Swift

Answer (score 0):

```
class ThisFails {
    func foo() -> PA {
        return X().test()   // error: generic parameter 'U' could not be inferred
    }
}

X().test() as PA            // error: generic parameter 'U' could not be inferred
```

Check next lines

```
X().test()       // error: generic parameter 'U' could not be inferred
X().test() as CB // no error
```

The question is how to make an instance of unknown type. everithing the compiler knows is that the type should conform to protocol. it is not enought, is it?

```
tryclass ThisFails {
    func foo<U:PA>() -> U {
        return X().test()
    }
}
```